# How to amend my existing R codes so that the output is limited only to this specific condition?

Tags: r, combinations

I am using `R` in `RStudio` and I have the following `list`:

```
list1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
```

I want to output all the combinations of 3 numbers (without replacement) from this `list` that would `sum` to, say, 50.

I am thinking of using the `RcppAlgos` `library` in `R`. I have the following codes:

```
list1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
uni <- unique(list1)
myRep <- rle(list1)$lengths
ans <- 50

library(RcppAlgos)
lapply(seq_along(uni), function(x) {
    comboGeneral(uni, x, freqs = myRep,
                 constraintFun = "sum",
                 comparisonFun = "==",
                 limitConstraints = ans)
})
```

If I will run this code, it will output ALL combinations that would sum to 50.

How can I limit the output only to those combinations with 3 numbers?

I also want the output to show ALL the results instead of giving me a "maximum reached" message.

Note: I am open to using another package, if available.

Comment: If you need only 3 numbers, then why looping through `seq_along(uni)`,  Instead, the 'x' should be 3?

Comment: I am quite new to R. Can you help further please?

Comment: I meant that you need `comboGeneral(uni, 3, freqs = myRep,
                  constraintFun = "sum",
                  comparisonFun = "==",
                  limitConstraints = ans)`. Here, the `seq_along(uni)` loop is just printing 1, 2, 3, ... length(un1).  and within the `comboGeneral`, it is instructing to get the 'n' column combinations

Comment: Ok, got your point. Please post as an answer and I'll vote accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lapply(seq_along(uni)` is looping through the sequence of 'uni' and this is going to the 'm' argument (i.e. number of elements to choose).  In the first case, it does 1, then 2, and so on. In our particular case, only 3 is needed and we don't need a loop for that

```
comboGeneral(uni, 3, freqs = myRep, constraintFun = "sum", 
      comparisonFun = "==", limitConstraints = ans)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this :)

```
list1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)

# combn generates all possible combinations when selecting 3 items from list1
combs = combn(list1, 3)

# select all combs which sum up to 50 (just transposed the matrix to have the combinations rowwise)
t(combs[,colSums(combs) == 50])
# check if we got the right combinations
rowSums(t(combs[,colSums(combs) == 50]))
```

if you need to speed this up, you could remove some values from list before doing it. The lowest number that could lead to a sum of 50 is 11 (since the two biggest values in the list are 20 and 19). So you could remove 1 to 10 before.